# Proving that a relation on the set of all polynomials with real coefficients is not linear

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

Helllo! I have the following exercise:

> Let R[t] be the set of all polynomials with real coefficients, and define p ≤ q if
> and only if p(x) ≤ q(x) for all real values of x. Prove this defines a partial ordering of
> R[t], but that this partial ordering is not a linear ordering.

To be able to prove that this defines a partial ordering we need to prove reflexivity, antisymmetry and transitivity.

1. Reflexivity is easy: $p(x) \le p(x)$ for all real values of $x$.
2. Anti-symmetry is not hard: If $p(x) \le q(x)$ for all values of $x$, then $q(x) \le p(x)$ for all values of $x$ only if they are the same polynomial.
3. Transitivity: I think it's directly implied from the $" \le "$ relation, which is transitive.

However, I have trouble proving that this is **NOT** a linear relation in the set $R[t]$. I'm not sure why, since it would mean that that neither $p(x) \le q(x)$ and $q(x) \le p(x)$ are true.

The only example I could think of was if $p(x) = x$ and $q(x) = x^2$, so $p(2) \le q(2)$ but $q(0.5) \le p(0.5)$ which would mean that $p(x) \le q(x)$ does not hold for all real $x$.

However, I'm confused. Judging by the definition of the relation, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ wouldn't even be in the relation at all, so this wouldn't disprove linearity.

**What I have come up with:** Linearity would imply that for each two polynomials, the first one must be related to the other one or vice-versa. Since I have provided a counterexample, it does not hold.

**My question is:** Is this a valid counterexample? If yes, do I need to add something to my explanations of reflexivity, anti-symmetry and transitivity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the right idea. A relation $\leq$ on $R[t]$ is *linear* (or *total*) if for every pair of elements $p(t), q(t) \in R[t]$, either $p(t) \leq q(t)$ or $q(t) \leq p(t)$. You've exhibited a counterexample, so you've shown that your relation is not linear.

Quick comment on notation: $R[t]$ is the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $R$ *in the variable $t$*, so it makes more sense to write the elements of $R[t]$ as polynomials $p(t)$, rather than $p(x)$.

Coming back to your example, it doesn't really make sense to say $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ aren't in the relation. You can think of the relation as a subset of $R[t] \times R[t]$, namely the set of all ordered pairs $(p(t), q(t))$ such that $p(t) \leq q(t)$. So it would be accurate to say that $(t, t^2)$ and $(t^2, t)$ are not in the relation, but there are ordered pairs in the relation that do contain these polynomials, like $(t, t+1)$ or $(t^2, 2t^2)$.

Comment: what I meant by not being in the relation was not being related at all. That's for example if I had a set $A = \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \} $ and the relation $R = \{ (0,1), (1,2), 3,4) \} $. We can see that $5$ and $6$ aren't related to any element.$

But now that I think about it, an element of the set not "belonging" to the relation it is defined on would violate transitivity, symmetry and reflexivity right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 5 and 6 don't belong to any ordered pair in the relation, but if the relation is reflexive, then it needs to have at least $(5, 5)$ and $(6, 6)$.